# php - get rid of duplicate items from array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays

how to remove duplicates in php associative array? The array is created from JSON.

```
    array (size=646)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
      public 'city' => string 'NY' (length=2)

  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Henry' (length=5)
      public 'city' => string 'Mexico' (length=6)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Jordan' (length=6)
      public 'city' => string 'Lake' (length=4)
              ...
```

I've tried to use `array_unique($data)` but I'm still getting the duplicate values. I just want to get those unique elements by its `id`. TIA.

Comment: Do you consider duplicate values as objects with the same `id` property? Which of the two given objects with `id = 2` has the higher priority?

Comment: Yes as I'm going to display it in a table.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is the second or first or whatever.

Comment: `array_unique()` doesn't work for objects. How would you expect it to know that it should just check `element->id`?

Comment: You can reindex the array by id: `$unique = array_column($array, null, 'id');` (Needs PHP 7)

Comment: @Barmar To be fair, all answers in the question that you've pointed, are so rubbish...

Comment: @VisioN: I agree.

Comment: What @Don'tPanic says and for PHP < 7 just decode as arrays instead.

Comment: Oh, that's true @AbraCadaver. I didn't notice it was from JSON when I made that comment.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
$arr = array_values(array_reduce($arr, function($arr, $x) {
    $arr[$x->id] = $x;
    return $arr;
}, []));
```